# Failed to load application.properties file while using @DataJpaTest annotation

Tags: spring, unit-testing, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to load application properties in Spring boot project for testing. I am also using @DataJpaTest annotation. Many people suggested to use @TestPropertySource annotation with combination of @datajpaTest but it is not loading properties. It is loading properties if I user @SpringBooTest.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
public class EntityRepositoryTests {
}
```

My application properties file is in main/resource/ folder.
It is working if I use `@SpringBootTest(properties = { "classpath:application.properties" }` but I have

```
 @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
```

which is failing to autoconfigure with SpringBootTest. I have also tried `@ContextConfiguration(initializers=ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)` but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

For test you must use

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```

along with application-test.properties

These are what I just used

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest(showSql = false)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
```